# Why can I not start the Vue UI after installing the Vue CLI?

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-cli

Using the following:

```
node 8.11.2
npm 6.3.0
```

I then try to install the *Vue CLI* (**@vue/cli@3.0.0**):

```
npm i -g @vue/cli
```

but when I run the following command:

```
vue ui
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es7.object.entries'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Apps\caches\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\apollo-upload-server\lib\mi
ddleware.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out I had to install the ***core-js*** package explicitly.

```
npm i -g core-js
```

<s>Not sure why this wasn't installed as a dependency though.</s>

The issue has been reported [HERE](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2215) and has been fixed in [v3.0.1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/releases/tag/v3.0.1).

Comment: Fixed it ,by this answer

Comment: still no luck for me, in truth i am not even getting an error, nothing.